# Transpose of a Matrix 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

Please enlighten me on how to create a C program that finds the transpose of an order 5 matrix represented by a two-dimensional (2D) array. Initialize the 2D array with elements as shown below in the original matrix using the initializer list. Display the original matrix and the transpose. There must only be one 2D array in the program.

Example:

Original matrix

```
1    2    3    4       5

6      7       8       9       10

11     12      13      14      15

16     17      18      19      20

21     22      23      24      25
```

Transpose of the Matrix:

```
1      6       11      16      21

2      7       12      17      22

3      8       13      18      23

4      9       14      19      24

5      10      15      20      25
```

Comment: Please show some actual code to represent the matrix.

Comment: You want to transpose a matrix in place? Think of how you'd reverse a list: you do a series of swaps until you're done. Now think about this in the case of the matrix: A[i,j] <-> A[j,i]. I smell a nested loop in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there must be only one array in the program, a valid approach would be to transpose the matrix in-place, which can be done with the following nested loops.

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for ( j = i+1; j < n; j++ ) // only the upper is iterated
    {
        swap(&(a[i][j]), &(a[j][i]));
    }
}
```

The following subroutine would perform the swapping, where pointers to `int` are used. In the calling code above, these are obtained by using the addresses of the elements to be swapped.

```
void swap(int* arg1, int* arg2)
{
    int buffer = *arg1;
    *arg1 = *arg2;
    *arg2 = buffer;
}
```

Comment: Would it be valid to transpose the matrix in-place? If so, it could be done by iterating over the right upper triangle and swapping entries along the diagonal. However, this also sort of involved swapping of indices, but the matrix is stored explicitly afterwards.

Comment: Yes I think it is valid.

Comment: I get an error warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]     *arg1 = arg2;

Comment: I mistyped the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Transpose of a given matrix can be calculated as below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int c,r,i,j;
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r,&c);
    int arr[r][c];
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter element : ");
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nOriginal array is : \n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("\nTranspose array is : \n");
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<r;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",arr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[5][5]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};

//transpose
cout<<"TRANSPOSE"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){   
  for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)  {      
    if(array[i]>array[j]){           
      int temp;              
      temp=array[i][j];               
      array[i][j]=array[j][i];                
      array[j][i]=temp;
    }      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As question asks only for **displaying** a transpose... it should be easy to.

```
int matrix[5][5] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
        std::cout<<matrix[j][i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

EDIT 1: replace cout with printf to get it working in C compiler